# Regarding accessing Digg API after getting access token

Tags: java, oauth, digg

I am getting an exception and status of code as 400. What's the problem in my code?

```
OAuthConsumer consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer("API key","Secret",SignatureMethod.HMAC_SHA1);
    OAuthProvider provider = new DefaultOAuthProvider(consumer,"http://services.digg.com/oauth/request_token","http://services.digg.com/oauth/access_token","http://digg.com/oauth/authorize");
    System.out.println("Fetching request token from Digg...");

    String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(OAuth.OUT_OF_BAND);

    System.out.println("Request token: " + consumer.getToken());
    System.out.println("Token secret: " + consumer.getTokenSecret());

    System.out.println("Now visit:\n" + authUrl
            + "\n... and grant this app authorization");
    System.out.println("Enter the PIN code and hit ENTER when you're done:");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String pin = br.readLine();

    System.out.println("Fetching access token from Digg...");

    provider.retrieveAccessToken(pin);

    System.out.println("Access token: " + consumer.getToken());
    System.out.println("Token secret: " + consumer.getTokenSecret());


     URL url = new URL("http://services.digg.com/2.0/story.digg");
     HttpURLConnection request =  (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
     request.setDoOutput(true);
     String charset="UTF-8";
             request.setRequestProperty("story_id","20100706205455:22419803" );
             request.setRequestProperty("key",consumer.getConsumerKey() );
             request.setRequestProperty("secret",consumer.getConsumerSecret()  );
             request.setRequestProperty("access_token" ,consumer.getToken() );
             request.setRequestProperty("access_token_secret",consumer.getTokenSecret()  );

     request.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
    request.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + charset);
    OutputStream output = null;
    try {
         output = request.getOutputStream();

    } finally {
         if (output != null) try { output.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
    }
    System.out.print(request.getResponseCode());
```

---

The exception is following :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://services.digg.com/2.0/story.digg
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1296)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1290)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:944)
        at oauthapplication.Main.main(Main.java:97)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://services.digg.com/2.0/story.digg
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1241)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:373)
        at oauthapplication.Main.main(Main.java:96)
400Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Please use this as reference http://developers.digg.com/version2/story-digg

Comment: Please include the output you get before the exception occurs.